# neo4j-shell Connection refused java.rmi.ConnectException

Tags: neo4j

I correctly start server:

> ~/Downloads/neo4j-community-3.2.1/bin $ ./neo4j start Active database:
>   graph.db Directories in use:   home:
>   /home/user/Downloads/neo4j-community-3.2.1   config:
>   /home/user/Downloads/neo4j-community-3.2.1/conf   logs:
>   /home/user/Downloads/neo4j-community-3.2.1/logs   plugins:
>   /home/user/Downloads/neo4j-community-3.2.1/plugins   import:
>   /home/user/Downloads/neo4j-community-3.2.1/import   data:
>   /home/user/Downloads/neo4j-community-3.2.1/data   certificates:
>   /home/user/Downloads/neo4j-community-3.2.1/certificates   run:
>   /home/user/Downloads/neo4j-community-3.2.1/run Starting Neo4j.
>   WARNING: Max 1024 open files allowed, minimum of 40000 recommended.
>   See the Neo4j manual. Started neo4j (pid 29246). It is available at
>   http://localhost:7474/ There may be a short delay until the server is
>   ready. See /home/user/Downloads/neo4j-community-3.2.1/logs/neo4j.log
>   for current status.

then when I try to launch the neo4j-shell:

> ~/Downloads/neo4j-community-3.2.1/bin $ ./neo4j-shell -v ERROR (-v for expanded information):     Connection
>   refused java.rmi.ConnectException: Connection refused to host:
>   localhost; nested exception is:   java.net.ConnectException:
>   Connection refused    at
>   sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPEndpoint.newSocket(TCPEndpoint.java:619)     at
>   sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPChannel.createConnection(TCPChannel.java:216)
>     at
>   sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPChannel.newConnection(TCPChannel.java:202)
>     at sun.rmi.server.UnicastRef.newCall(UnicastRef.java:342)   at
>   sun.rmi.registry.RegistryImpl_Stub.lookup(Unknown Source)     at
>   java.rmi.Naming.lookup(Naming.java:101)   at
>   org.neo4j.shell.impl.RmiLocation.getBoundObject(RmiLocation.java:191)
>     at
>   org.neo4j.shell.impl.RemoteClient.findRemoteServer(RemoteClient.java:72)
>     at org.neo4j.shell.impl.RemoteClient.(RemoteClient.java:65)   at
>   org.neo4j.shell.impl.RemoteClient.(RemoteClient.java:46)    at
>   org.neo4j.shell.ShellLobby.newClient(ShellLobby.java:204)     at
>   org.neo4j.shell.StartClient.startRemote(StartClient.java:358)     at
>   org.neo4j.shell.StartClient.start(StartClient.java:229)   at
>   org.neo4j.shell.StartClient.main(StartClient.java:147) Caused by:
>   java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused     at
>   java.net.PlainSocketImpl.socketConnect(Native Method)     at
>   java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.doConnect(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:350)
>     at
>   java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connectToAddress(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:206)
>     at
>   java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connect(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:188)
>     at java.net.SocksSocketImpl.connect(SocksSocketImpl.java:392)   at
>   java.net.Socket.connect(Socket.java:589)  at
>   java.net.Socket.connect(Socket.java:538)  at
>   java.net.Socket.(Socket.java:434)   at
>   java.net.Socket.(Socket.java:211)   at
>   sun.rmi.transport.proxy.RMIDirectSocketFactory.createSocket(RMIDirectSocketFactory.java:40)
>     at
>   sun.rmi.transport.proxy.RMIMasterSocketFactory.createSocket(RMIMasterSocketFactory.java:148)
>     at sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPEndpoint.newSocket(TCPEndpoint.java:613)
>     ... 13 more
>
> -host      Domain name or IP of host to connect to (default:
>   localhost)  -port      Port of host to connect to (default: 1337) 
>   -name      RMI name, i.e. rmi://:/ (default: shell)  -pid       Process ID to connect to  -c         Command line to execute. After executing it the shell exits  -file      File
>   containing commands to execute, or '-' to read from stdin. After
>   executing it the shell exits  -readonly  Connect in readonly mode
>   (only for connecting with -path)  -path      Points to a neo4j db path
>   so that a local server can be started there  -config    Points to a
>   config file when starting a local server
>
> Example arguments for remote:     -port 1337  -host 192.168.1.234 -port
>   1337 -name shell  -host localhost -readonly   ...or no arguments for
>   default values Example arguments for local:   -path /path/to/db   -path
>   /path/to/db -config /path/to/neo4j.config     -path /path/to/db -readonly

the server is in its default initial configuration, the only thing I changed is the graph username and password.

Answer (score 6):

`neo4j-shell` is deprecated since version `3.1`, you should use `cypher-shell` instead.

But you can enable it by adding this configuration : `dbms.shell.enabled=true`

Cheers.

Comment: Ok fixed, still can't figure out why they left the neo4j-shell executable in version 3.2 along with the cypher-shell executable if the former doesn't work and one should use the latter. And not even a notice inside the bin/ folder with the two executables regarding the need for the dbms.shell.enabled=true option

Comment: deprecated = still there and will be remove on the next major version (so the v4). So it's normal to have it.